# someone knows the algorithm to avoid that two or more datetimes collide between them in php

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I want to find the correct algorithm to avoid collision between datetime variables.

I mean for example we don't want the one wedding collide with other one in the same hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make two checks because, from what you've stated, you don't know which of the two events starts first. So, this is what you do in mysql, assuming that you've joined two rows and one is called `a` and one is called `b` and they each have a datetime field for `start` and `end`:

```
select ...your query...
where (
    a.end<=b.start or b.end<=a.start
) ... continue your query here if you want...
```

I changed this. You don't want ANY overlap. So, all you need to do is ensure one ends before the other one starts. Simplifies the query.

The same logic us used if you have some sort of PHP variables. I'll use $a_start, $a_end, $b_start, and $b_end as an example:

```
if($a_end<=$b_start || $b_end<=$a_start) // You are good!
```

I used <=, so one can end at the exact time another starts. Use just < if you don't want that microsecond of overlap.

Comment: yeah but in both cases, they have to be in the database, I mean both.

Comment: sorry if my question is bad?

Comment: my problem is about one user insert one new row in the database in a busy date

Comment: Your question doesn't state what variables you are using, what tables you are using, what fields are in those tables, etc... So, it is IMPOSSIBLE for me to write code you can copy and paste. All I can do is explain that you have to make two checks and show examples of making those two checks.

Comment: sorry it is a searching work to a simple question. Thanks by your attention. So with that "if" I can avoid the user insert in busy dates?

Comment: It appears that you may want to ask a different question (I'd suggest actually making a new question). It think you want to ask: Given a database table with events that have a start and end datetime, I have a new event with a start and end datetime. How can I quickly see if the new event overlaps any event in the database table?